# Use ld on 64-bit platform to generate 32-bit executable

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, ld

I wrote an assembly that is assemble with:

```
$as --32 -o hello.o hello.s
```

Then I tried to generate an executable with:

```
$ld -o hello hello.o
```

It gives me an error:

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `ConditionalBranching.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I tried using flag -m32 or --32, but ld dont take them. I cannot find a solution by reading the man page of ld. How can I generate a 32-bit binary from my 32-bit shared object?

Comment: Use `ld -melf_i386`.

Answer (score 8):

Your linker is attempting to create a 64-bit binary, but your assembly code was assembled for a 32-bit architecture. This creates a mismatch.

Fix this by passing the `-m elf_i386` flag to your linker, explicitly instructing it to create a 32-bit binary.

Comment: ld: warning: option -m is obsolete and being ignored :(

Comment: @somerandomdev49: What `ld` version are you using?  `ld -melf_i386` still works for me in GNU Binutils 2.40.0 (from 2023, on an up-to-date x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux system).