# Linking 32 bit files on 64 bit machine with ld

Tags: c, nasm, ld

I am compiled my assembly files with `nasm`:

```
nasm -felf32 test.nasm -o test.o
```

I've done it on 64 bit OS. Now, I would like to link it with:
My OS is Ubuntu.

```
gcc -m32 test.o -o test
```

but I cannot because I have not installed 32-bit libraries.
I know that I should install 32bit libraries and it is a solution. But, I cannot install because I am not root. Can I solve that problem in another way? For example, to use `ld` and download need `*.so` files from the Internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184929/use-ld-on-64-bit-platform-to-generate-32-bit-executable

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`   . When asked for the pasword, that is the password of the user account you logged in as. SUDO will elevate your privileges to do the install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ld on 64-bit platform to generate 32-bit executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184929/use-ld-on-64-bit-platform-to-generate-32-bit-executable)

Comment: "sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib . When asked for the pasword, that is the password of the user account you logged in as. SUDO will elevate your privileges to do the install." It doesn't work in my case. I `ssh` to my university's account and I have no privilages to install something beyond /home/ directory.

Comment: I tried use to `ld -melf_i386`. It is not sufficient because I have to link with `libc`